# What do you call a set that has recurring elements of another set?

Tags: set-theory

Example:

A = {1,2,3,4}

B = {1,1,1,3,4,4}

B contains some (or all) elements of A, some (or all) of which are recurring.

What do you call this relationship and what is its mathematical notation?

Comment: Sets do not contain duplicates

Comment: What about "Multisets"?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset

Comment: For your application, is $\{1,1,1,3,4,4\} = \{1,3,4,1,4,1\}$ ?  If YES, then you may be talking about a multiset.  If NO, then you may be talking about a sequence or a list.

Comment: For my application, the order does not matter.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence